# How to capture each linux command before sending it out?

Tags: linux, history

I want to monitor the server at a more strict history.
Since each user can delete their own history file, it is better to capture each command to a history file in the background, which is unaccessible by them.
I have already set up an udp server, and know how to send anything to that port via nc:

```
echo [command string] | nc -u [port]
```

Is there a way to capture each command string once it is entered in the prompt?

Comment: Use auditd to capture executed commands. It is built into the Kernel and would require elevated privileges to modify the generated logs. Ideally, you would forward this log to a remote host with very limited access.

Comment: Additionally RHEL 8 and CentOS support `tlog` session recording https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/recording_sessions/index

Comment: Note that recording terminals in graphical sessions is not supported by `tlog` because a graphical session has a single audit session ID for all terminals and `tlog` does not have a way to distinguish between the terminals and prevent repeated recordings.